# Webpack: Induce failure of live reload and build if there exists a Jest-test with compilation-errors or ESLint-errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jestjs, eslint

I have a React-Webpack project of medium complexity that uses a typical chain of TypeScript/Webpack-dev-server, Jest and related tools.
The setup is very similar to `create-react-app`, but it deviated a bit over the time: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/

If there exists a compilation-error or ESLint-error in the web-served TypeScript files, then Webpack rejects both the build and the live reload. This is the expected behavior.

However, if there are one or more non-compiling tests, then Webpack ignores the tests and continues to serve the web-code!
This is highly problematic because it leads to a situation where broken tests get pushed to our Git-repo again and again.

What I want to do:
**How can I induce a failure of both builds and live reload if there exists a test with compilation-errors or ESLint-errors?**

Note that all those tests are running in Node.js via the Jest test execution framework, whereas the actual app runs in the browser.

**Preliminary investigation:**

It seems that WebPack ignores all tests because of the following `reportFiles` configuration for `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin`:

```
      reportFiles: [
        '**',
        '!**/__tests__/**',
        '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
        '!**/src/setupProxy.*',
        '!**/src/setupTests.*',
      ],
```

If I remove the `'!**/__tests__/**'` and `'!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*'`, then I get the desired build failures (but not live reload failures). However, this might lead to a whole new bunch of problems.

Comment: what about to check on commit? https://medium.com/gits-apps-insight/utilizing-git-hook-by-using-eslint-husky-and-lint-staged-18b6f6f60f1e

Comment: Yes, checking all tests on commit might be feasible, but I would rather like to fail the live reload.